# session.setAttribute("authManager", manager) throws a NotSerializableException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, serialization, socialauth

I'm trying to use SocialAuth and i'm setting it up according to this guide:
https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth/wiki/Getting-Started-with-implementing-SocialAuth

It goes well, except for the part `session.setAttribute("authManager", manager);` which throws a NotSerializableException. According to the guide I have to store the SocialAuthManager object in the session, however it gives me this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager$SerializableObjectsOnlyHttpSession.checkCanSerialize(SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager.java:66)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager$SerializableObjectsOnlyHttpSession.setAttribute(SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager.java:43)
    at cd.orbit.server.AuthServlet.doPost(AuthServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager$SerializableObjectsOnlyHttpSession.checkCanSerialize(SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager.java:64)
    ... 39 more
```

Now how do I use this? Anyone familiar with the SocialAuth library?

Comment: What is the class name for session object you are using here?

Comment: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getSession() -> HttpSession

Comment: My guess is that `manager` object isn't serializable

Comment: SocialAuthManager does implement the Serializable interface. It's a class from the library, however it still throws the NotSerializableException.

Comment: Please see http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=20148

Comment: I don't see how this answers my problem, the class is Serializable.

Comment: Having `implements Serializable` on the class definition doesn't guarantee that every instance of the class is Serializable indeed.
From looking into class code https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/source/browse/trunk/socialauth-core/src/org/brickred/socialauth/SocialAuthManager.java?r=383 it looks like `providersMap` could include non-serializable data in it. `Log` implementation could be non-serializable too.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to store `manager` object on the `HttpSession`.
Be aware that the objects that you store on the session has to be serializable.
It looks like [SocialAuthManager class](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/source/browse/trunk/socialauth-core/src/org/brickred/socialauth/SocialAuthManager.java?r=383) isn't really `Serializable` even though it claims so:

- `SocialAuthConfig` isn't serializable
- A `Log` implementation object could be non-serializable
- The values within `providersMap` could be non-serializable

Comment: I understand, but the 'getting started' states explicitly to "Store !!SocialAuthManager object in session". So how would I do this now, or what do if I don't store it?